# Add blur on non-input div fields not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm trying to match the styling that bootstrap applies to `input` fields to a parent `div`. I've removed the said `:active` and `:focus` styling from the child `input` elements and am trying to use the `contentEditable` tag in the parent `div` element but I'm getting the following error.
Any help would greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at a.validator.escapeCssMeta (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
at a.validator.errorsFor (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
at a.validator.prepareElement (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
at a.validator.element (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
at a.validator.onfocusout (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
at HTMLDivElement.b (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.simulate (jquery.min.js:2)
```

```js
$('.add-btn-outline').on('click', function() {
  console.log('focus');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})

$('.add-btn-outline').on('blur', function() {
  console.log('blur');
  $(this).removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.remove-btn-outline:focus,
.remove-btn-outline:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.add-btn-outline.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
  border-color: #80bdff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="BankSortCode" class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="form-control add-btn-outline" contentEditable onclick="$(this).children(':first').select();">
    <input class="autoTabInput max_chars-2 border-0 remove-btn-outline" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="99"> -
    <input class="autoTabInput max_chars-2 border-0 remove-btn-outline" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="99"> -
    <input class="autoTabInput max_chars-2 border-0 remove-btn-outline" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="99">
  </div>
  <span asp-validation-for="BankSortCode" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tends to happen when you don't put a name for your form. Try and do that to fix the issue.

EDIT : After looking closely, you try to listen to the blur event on the elements bearing the class `add-btn-outline`. But that element is a div and I'm not sure it will trigger that kind of event. I was able to achieve a blur effect by changing the second event function by instead listening the blur function from the inputs and changing the style of the parent :

```
$('.add-btn-outline').on('click', function() {
  console.log('focus');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})

//changed this one
$('.remove-btn-outline').blur(function() {
  console.log('blur');
  $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
})
```

JsFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/j8kwfeoz/1/

Comment: The edited answer seems right. `<div>` doesn't receive focus, so it can't trigger a blur event, either.

Comment: **Boom!** Thanks Raekh Void!